# URL does not show properly after fetching to show in iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I  saved a URL into database properly using EF in ASP.Net MVC4:
The URL is like below:

```
 www.abc.com?id=a&name=value
```

But when I retrieved it & try to show in iframe as src then

```
 & is converted to &amp;amp;
```

Example:

```
<iframe width="500" height="400" src="www.abc.com?id=a&amp;amp;name=value">
```

How can I display exact url? 
like below:

```
   src="www.abc.com?id=a&name=value"
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Option # 1**

Are u using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` while retrieving the data and `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` while saving into database ?

*Code example*

```
string value1 = "&lt;html&gt;";
string value2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value1);   //<html>
string value3 = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value2);   //&lt;html&gt;
```

### **Option # 2**

Once the data is saved in Database using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`, you can use `Html.Raw` to `Decode` it, like below.

*Code Example*

```
@Html.Raw("&lt;html&gt") //gives <html>
```